# How to output MySQL query results in CSV with correct format?

Tags: mysql, bash, csv

I have the below script

mysql -uleuser -plepassword -a ledb -e "select dr.order_id, dr.system_name from tschedule drtv where dr.system_name not in (select system_name from ca_tmc_site);" > $baselogdir/$datelogdir/$logfilename

the csv file(logfilename.csv) which is extracting is not in correct format

It gets messy and all mixed up for just two columns,is it because of  the tab or spaces?

Answer (score 0):

try this: `mysql -uleuser -plepassword -a ledb -ss -e "select dr.order_id, dr.system_name from tschedule drtv where dr.system_name not in (select system_name from ca_tmc_site);" | sed "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g” > $baselogdir/$datelogdir/$logfilename`